# Delete the duplicate arrays inside an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to ignore the duplicates from an array that has multiple array in lowest running cost. For example;

```
A = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['1','2'],['3','4'],['7','8']]
```

the expected output should be like as

```
Output = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['7','8']]
```

Is it possible to compare arrays inside an array.
I am doing in this way;

```
 A = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['1','2'],['3','4'],['7','8']]
        output = set()
        for x in A:
            output.add(x)
        print (output)
```

But it prompts;

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You can't put a list in a set because a list is not hashable. And even if that worked, you'll lose the ordering of the items.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Order does not matter but the cost matters.

Comment: Also, those are lists, not [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something simple like:

```
B = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, A))))
```

Here's my "bakeoff" -- please let me know if I've misrepresented your solution:

```
import timeit
from random import choice

DIGITS = list("123456789")

# one million elements in list
A = [[choice(DIGITS), choice(DIGITS)] for _ in range(1000000)]

def elena(A):  # MrName's solution is identical
    B = []

    for i in A:
        if i not in B:
            B.append(i)
    return B

def cdlane(A):

    return list(map(list, set(map(tuple, A))))

def VikashSingh(A):
    uniques = set()
    B = []

    for x in A:
        val = '-'.join([str(key) for key in x])
        if val not in uniques:
            B.append(x)
            uniques.add(val)
    return B

def AbhilekhSingh(A):
    def unique_elements(l):
        last = object()
        for item in l:
            if item == last:
                continue
            yield item
            last = item

    return list(unique_elements(sorted(A)))

# sanity check to make sure everyone one agrees on the answer
B = sorted(elena(A))
assert(B == sorted(cdlane(A)))
assert(B == sorted(VikashSingh(A)))
assert(B == sorted(AbhilekhSingh(A)))

print("elena:", format(timeit.timeit('B = elena(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".3"))

print("cdlane:", format(timeit.timeit('B = cdlane(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".3"))

print("VikashSingh:", format(timeit.timeit('B = VikashSingh(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".3"))

print("AbhilekhSingh:", format(timeit.timeit('B = AbhilekhSingh(A)', number=10, globals=globals()), ".3"))
```

RESULTS

```
elena: 17.5
cdlane: 2.04
VikashSingh: 10.0
AbhilekhSingh: 8.83
```

Comment: Kindly mention the running cost as well.

Comment: This will change the order of the list elements, though, which might or might not be a problem.

Comment: What is the running cost?

Comment: @sphericalcowboy, that was already addressed by the OP in the comments to his post.

Comment: @cdlane: Ah! Had to refresh, only seeing it now.

Comment: @cdlane What is the running cost of this line of code?

Comment: I think it would be `m * n * n`. first `m * n` when we create initial set of tupple. Then iterate over that set which should be `order(n)` so `m * n * n`.

Comment: @VikashSingh Can we do it in log(n)?

Comment: I don't think `log(n)` is possible. Because if `log(n)` was possible we could reverse engineer it and use it for sorting of list. which we know can not be `log(n)`.

Comment: @Awais, what is with the impatience?  It's a tricky comparison as the other solutions are looping in Python whereas this one is looping in **C** so that should provide a nice performance boost.  And whereas @VikashSingh does `'-'.join([str(key) for key in x])` to make a hashable item, this one simply does tuple(['1', '2']) which has to be more efficient.  Personally, I'd prefer a timed bakeoff to see which of the many candidates are fastest rather than potentially incorrect guestimates...

Comment: Think of it this way, Imagine list is `[1,2,3]` To know that this has all unique values you can at best have `O(n)` at the very best.

Comment: @cdlane seems like your solution works better. Checking for bigger lists now.

Comment: cdlane: I checked for 1Million values in list. your solution is 3 times faster than mine. @Awais : go with this as order of the values doesn't matter to you.

Comment: All operations here are obviously O(n) except the set creation. Since sets are hashtable-based, the set creation is also O(n), since both hashtable lookup and insertion are O(1). If a tree was used for a set, the set creation step would be O(n log n). In practice, the constant for the hashtable could be high enough (e.g. due to hash collisions) so that a tree implementation would be faster up to a certain n.

Answer (score 1):

```
List length: n
Element length: m 
Complexity: 
    Iterate on n
    Format key by iterating on m
    Check key exists is set `uniques` in O(1)
    Total running time is is O(n * m)
```

one simple way to do this is:

```
uniques = set()
output = []
for x in A:
    val = '-'.join([str(key) for key in x])
    if val not in uniques:
        output.append(x)
        uniques.add(val)
print (output)
```

output:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

Comment: Kindly mention the running cost as well. I think it has o(n). is it?

Comment: O(n) running time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
In [27]: A = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['1','2'],['3','4'], ['7','8']]

In [28]: new_list = []

In [29]: for i in A:
    ...:     if i not in new_list:
    ...:         new_list.append(i)
    ...:         

In [30]: new_list
Out[30]: [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

Comment: Kindly mention the running cost as well. I think it has o(n). is it?

Comment: `if i not in new_list:` won't this be a costly step and make the process n^2?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list and compare every element with it's previous one.

```
List length: n
Element length: m 
Complexity: Sorting(n * log(n) * m) + Comparison(n * m) = Total(n * log(n) * m)
```

Try this:

```
def unique_elements(l):
    last = object()
    for item in l:
        if item == last:
            continue
        yield item
        last = item

def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(unique_elements(sorted(l)))
```

Comment: Kindly mention the running cost as well. I think it has o(n). is it?

Comment: Added the running cost and let me know of you have any questions regarding it.

Comment: your solution on 1Million list is giving `CPU times: user 1.21 s, sys: 17.9 ms, total: 1.23 s`

Answer (score 1):

Another potentially simple solution, but not sure how the "cost" would compare to other presented solutions:

```
A = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['1','2'],['3','4'],['7','8']]

res = []
for entry in A:
    if not entry in res:
        res.append(entry)
```

Comment: For the input data provided, this solution is quite adequate, order-preserving, and as straightforward as it gets. For a list of 10000 lists, 1000 numbers each, it's going to be expensive.